# Some Javascript doesn't work on Blogger Dynamic View. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

Sorry for my English :(

I finding solution to fix some Javascript doesn't work on Blogger Dynamic View. I have no idea but some simple Javascript work normally like this (Random background image)

```
function changeImg(imgNumber) {
var myImages = ["url", "url", "url"];
var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
}
window.onload=changeImg;
```

I want to write table that can be sorted. But many Javascript doesn't work normally I tried [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) and this simple Javascript all not working (I copied from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37632/how-should-i-sort-an-html-table-with-javascript-in-a-more-efficient-manner))

```
<script>
    var people, asc1 = 1,
        asc2 = 1,
        asc3 = 1;
    window.onload = function () {
        people = document.getElementById("people");
    }

    function sort_table(tbody, col, asc) {
        var rows = tbody.rows,
            rlen = rows.length,
            arr = new Array(),
            i, j, cells, clen;
        // fill the array with values from the table
        for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
            cells = rows[i].cells;
            clen = cells.length;
            arr[i] = new Array();
            for (j = 0; j < clen; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
            }
        }
        // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
        arr.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1 * asc);
        });
        // replace existing rows with new rows created from the sorted array
        for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) {
            rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>" + arr[i].join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
        }
    }
</script>
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: none;
    }
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 4px 16px;
        font-family: Times New Roman;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    th {
        background-color: #C8C8C8;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 0, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1;">Name</th>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 1, asc2); asc2 *= -1; asc3 = 1; asc1 = 1;">Surname</th>
            <th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc3); asc3 *= -1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1;">Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="people">
        <tr>
            <td>Raja</td>
            <td>Dey</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mamata</td>
            <td>Sharma</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Avijit</td>
            <td>Sharma</td>
            <td>21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sharanya</td>
            <td>Dutta</td>
            <td>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nabin</td>
            <td>Roy</td>
            <td>27</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But on HTML text files is working normally. How can I fix it?

Comment: Your table sort works perfectly [http://valijon.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/123.html](http://valijon.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/123.html)

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work for Dynamic Views :(

Comment: here my table sort that not working: http://addressgaming.blogspot.com/p/heroes-data.html (If page not change yet)

Comment: Did you add **sort_table** function in your blog? Because, in *source code* I don't see that. I see this error in console **TypeError: tbody is undefined**